# Determining source of dependencies in MSVC's manifest generator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, manifest, winsxs

I am building an application using Microsoft Visual C++ 2005. After a major update of libraries, I am getting the following entry in my manifest file:

```
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT" version="8.0.50727.4053" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

However, when I look use the Dependency Walker on the resulting executable, I don't see MSVC80D.DLL in the list at all, which is a bit surprising to me.

I've also tried setting the linker to "verbose" mode, to see if it would tell me where the dependency indicated in the manifest is coming from. Alas, the information there doesn't shed any light on the problem.

I've also gone through all the libraries I'm linking to see if any of them use the debug CRT. As near as I can tell, none of them do.

How can I determine what library is causing this issue? When I distribute the executable as it is, I get a side-by-side error, presumably because of this entry in the auto-generated manifest.

Thanks so much for any help you can offer... After a few days of trying to figure out what's going on, I'm starting to get really frustrated with the problem.

Comment: I've spent another day trying to track down the problem, and think perhaps I can clarify. It seems clear at this point that the dependency is not coming from any of the actual libraries. I think the big thing I don't understand is this: Is it possible there is some other setting which is causing the manifest generator to include the debug CRT?

Comment: Another update: I decided to build a simple project and start including the libraries I use one at a time. Using this method, I determined that libjpeg is causing MSVC to add the "DebugCRT" line to the manifest.

The strange thing is that dumpbin shows no dependency on MSVCRTD in the libjpeg.lib file. Just to be sure, I rebuilt libjpeg with the nodebug=1 option, and got the same result.

My question now is: Why would the manifest generator be adding DebugCRT to the manifest when I add libjpeg, even though the library itself doesn't seem to depend on the debug CRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution to my problem. I decided to build a small test app, then add the libraries I'm using one at a time. Using this method, I isolated one library in particular that seemed to be causing the problem. I'm certain the library didn't show debug dependencies using dumpbin, but, on the other hand, I have been able to eliminate the unwanted manifest line by rebuilding that library.

Comment: It's possible that the library is using a #pragma that causes this entry to be generated in the manifest. As described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/31/2995284.aspx